# Pigeon hole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Out of eleven square integers we can pick six integers such that 
$a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2+e^2+f^2 \,(\mod 12)$

This was probably the toughest question in section b of our maths paper.I knew this question needs php but I couldn't bring the condition to enforce php.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start by figuring out the only possible values of a square $\pmod {12}$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that I had done that it's just 0,1,4,9.then what to do.

Comment: Show that out of these four values one of the following must happen: there are three that occur two times each; one that occurs four times and another twice; or one that occurs six times. In each of these cases you can do it.